# Where is the Standard User Analyzer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I downloaded the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) to install the Standard User Analyzer. I choose that as a feature that I want to install. However, I'm not seeing it anywhere on my computer. Anyone know how to launch or find this?

Here's the install option I chose: [image: Applicationj Compatibility Tools]

It's listed in the docs online too as being compatible with Windows 10: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/using-the-sua-wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing the ADK, you had to specify the location.

By default it's :

`c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10`

So, the path to Standard User Analyzer is, for example: `c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Application Compatibility Toolkit\Standard User Analyzer`